# Get password protected json via Retrofit2 in Android

Tags: android, json, web-services, url, retrofit2

I successfully consume a json without password protected but admin set a password and I cannot get data via Retrofit2. How can I fix this? Please share your ideas. Thanks.

Comment: What authentication method (Basic Authentication etc.) did the admin use?

Comment: @CliveSeebregts Yes, it is a basic authentication type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure your `OkHttpClient` with a new `Authenticator` to handle `Basic Auth` as follows:

```
 OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
     .authenticator(new Authenticator() {
         @Override
         public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) throws IOException {
             String credential = Credentials.basic("username", "password");
             return response.request().newBuilder()
                            .header("Authorization", credential)
                            .build();
          }
      }).build();
```

Then use the `OkHttpClient` in `Retrofit` as follows:

```
new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("url")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build();
```

Comment: You're awesome. Thanks for the code @Clive Seebregts